# what shape does this function $\delta_{x}(x)$ look like if it's a fractal what is it's fractal dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, fractals, fractal-analysis

what shape does this function $\delta_{x}(x)$ look like if it's a fractal what is its fractal dimension?

so $\alpha$ is a real number and $\delta_{\alpha}(x)$ is a function based of $\alpha$ written in base $2$

let's say $\alpha=101.001010100110100010..._2$ then
$$\delta_{\alpha}(x)=1+\frac{0x}{1!}+\frac{0x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{0x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\dots$$

when $\alpha$ in base two has finite digits or an endless string of $1$'s then $\delta_{\alpha}(x)$ isn't defined

my question is what shape does $\delta_{x}(x)$ make when plotted. I know that it's not a continuous function so I wonder if it's a fractal.

Comment: Since (for example) $0.01_2 = 0.001111\ldots_2$, should we use the terminating representation (when there is one)?  And just to be clear, you want to know what $\delta_\alpha(x)$ looks like *as a function of $x$*, for a given value of $\alpha$?  And finally, where did this problem come from?

Comment: @BrianTung I was wondering what does $\delta_x(x)$ look like then I realized it wasn't continuous so I wanted to know what is it? is it a fractal if it is then what is its fractal dimension? I just thought of it. the reason I say it's not defined it because there are two possible functions related to it and I didn't want a multi-function.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were diagonalizing it.  So let's just take the terminating version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the following function:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor 2^n x \rfloor - 2\lfloor 2^{n-1}x\rfloor}{n!}x^n. $$

This function coincides with $\delta_x(x)$ when $x$ is not a dyadic rational, and so, it suffices to study this function instead. Its graph looks like:

[image: Graph of f]

This function turns out to be of bounded variation on any interval, and in particular, the [Hausdorff dimension of its graph is exactly $1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327698/hausdorff-dimension-of-the-graph-of-a-bv-function-in-1-dimensional-setting). So, although the graph looks fun, I would not consider this as a fractal.

Indeed, if we write

$$ f_n(x) = \frac{\lfloor 2^n x \rfloor - 2\lfloor 2^{n-1}x\rfloor}{n!}x^n, $$

then for each positive integer $m$, the total variation of $f_n$ on $[-m, m]$ satisfies

\begin{align*}
V(f_n,[-m,m])
&\leq \frac{1}{n!} \left( \int_{-m}^{m} \left| \mathrm{d}(x^n) \right| + \int_{-m}^{m} m^n \left| \mathrm{d}(\lfloor 2^n x \rfloor - 2\lfloor 2^{n-1}x\rfloor) \right| \right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n!}(2m^n + (2m)^{n+1}).
\end{align*}

So it follows that

$$ V(f, [-m,m]) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}(2m^n + (2m)^{n+1}) < \infty, $$

and the desired claim follows.